# How to add an extra argument conditionally in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

There's a script that calls the other program. The following is `program.sh`. It might look non-sense but I'm omitting lots of details and… Let's say I wanna stick to the structure as is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function run_this {
    /usr/bin/foo -A -B -C
}
run_this
```

I wanna change the arguments passed to `/usr/bin/foo` by the argument passed to `program.sh`. So for example, if you call `program.sh --quiet` then `/usr/bin/foo -A -B -C -X`. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: if you are just passing all args to foo the use foo $* e.g. /usr/bin/foo -A -B -C $*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an array.

```
cmd=(/usr/bin/foo -A -B -C)
if somecond; then
  cmd+=(-X)
fi
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a conditional. I'm sure there are less repetitive ways to do it but this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

function run_this {
    if [[ "$1" = "--quiet" ]]; then
       /usr/bin/foo -A -B -C -X
    else 
       /usr/bin/foo -A -B -C
    fi
}
run_this "$1"
```